# python and yaml extract values of certain yaml field

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following scenario:

a yaml file:

```
team:
  owner: 
  contact:
  channel:
  role:
    role1: 3r
    role2: 6q
```

And a python script that needs to extract the keyvalue pairs of `role:`

```
def yaml_processor(role):
    filepath = "../1/2/3.yaml"
    data = yaml_loader(filepath)
    data = data.get(role)
    for team in data.iteritems():
        print(role)
    file.close()
```

Comment: are you getting an error or any other undesired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things strange in your code, but lets start with
defining `yaml_loader`:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

def yaml_loader(file_path):
   yaml = YAML()
   with open(file_path) as fp:
      data = yaml.load(fp)
   return data
```

that loads your YAML into a hierarchical data structure. At the root
of that structure is a dict, with one key: `team`, because at the root
of your document there is a mapping with that key.

As for your code:

- You always print the argument to `yaml_processor` for each team you
  find. You are not using the data from the YAML document
- you try to replace the data you get from the YAML document with
  `data.get(role)`, that will only work if `role == 'team'` because
  there is only that key at the root level
- you do `file.close()` what is `file`?
- you are using `.iteritems()` that is a Python 2 construct. Python 2
  is [end-of-life in
  2020](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/). Do you really
  intent to use learn to use Python 2 specific code this late in the game?

I would include:

```
from future import print_function
```

at the top of my program and then do something like:

```
def yaml_processor():
    # filepath = "../1/2/3.yaml"
    filepath = '3.yaml'  # different filestructure on my disc
    data = yaml_loader(filepath)
    for team in data:
        team_data = data[team]
        for role_nr in team_data['role']:
            role = team_data['role'][role_nr]
            print('team {}, role number: {}, role: {}'.format(team, role_nr, role))

yaml_processor()
```

which gives:

```
team team, role number: role1, role: 3r
team team, role number: role2, role: 6q
```

If you are not realy using the key `role1` and `role2` you should
consider using a sequence in your YAML document:

```
team:
  owner: 
  contact:
  channel:
  roles:
    - 3r
    - 6q
```